# WPF - Configurable UI

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

We currently have a basic implementation of configurable UI, but we feel like it's not the best way. We are developing another application that needs to be configurable from external file and we were wondering if there is a better way to do it.

We currently have xml file with elements with the name and availability which is directly translated to visibility. When the element is `available="false"` we hide the element with `visibility="collapsed"`. Elements are enclosed in a Setup element with name. There is separate configuration file with setup name that we want to load.

```xml
<Setup name="All">
    <Element name="toolBarDrawingTools" available="true"/>
    ...
</setup>
<Setup name="Operator">
    <Element name="toolBarDrawingTools" available="false"/>
    ...
</setup>
```

It works reasonably well, but we feel like it's not a great approach just to hide elements. A better approach might be to create and add only elements that we need. Layout should not be much of a problem because most element would be ToolBars, MenuItems or UserControls that would be added to StackPanels. So there is no complicated element positioning. What we also found is define xml files with XAML code and at run-time convert it to visual elements. We do not need that much complexity. We have a set of UserControls that we want to dynamically add.

We do not have a clear vision what we want. In the end, we could use our current approach and it would work. What we need is to define what elements will be in final window from external source without the need to recompile whole application.

So what I am asking is what options do we have, are there any "standardized" ways or frameworks. Do you know any articles or books on this topic? Or should we stick with the simplest approach and just hide what we don't want?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [AvalonDock](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/)

Comment: In my WPF project I used Prism + Regions, where each module can add some UI parts. And if you dont want to show some functional, you shouldnt load module.

Comment: *"we feel like it's not a great approach just to hide elements"*: If there's no concrete performance problem, don't worry about it. But a "correct" MVVM solution would be to implement your modules as viewmodels, which would be properties of the main viewmodel (or they're in a collection the main vm owns). The main view displays them in `ContentControl`s or an `ItemsControl`, with an implicit `DataTemplate` for each module. If a module `MainVM.Foo` is hidden, that means `MainVM.Foo` returns `null`. Or you remove it from `ObservableCollection<VMBase> MainVM.ChildCollections`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand you  are after a modular application development. So I  can suggest you to look at the next topics; **Modular Application Development Using Prism** in internet. For example, by this approach you can use the PRISM discovery mechanism(which uses the app.config file to define modules) in oreder to build whole user interface. Here are a couple of possible links:

1. [Building an Extensible Application with MEF, WPF, and MVVM](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/43625/building-an-extensible-application-with-mef-wpf-an).
2. [Modular Application Development Using Prism Library 5.0 for WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479(v=pandp.40).aspx).
3. [A MEF explanation topic](http://blogs.msmvps.com/bsonnino/2013/08/31/developing-modular-applications-with-mef/).

Let me know in case you will need more explanations.

Best regards.